# How does databinding works in Spark DropDownList

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, air, selecteditem, flex-spark

I have issues with updating the selectedItem property in Spark Drop Down List.

The list implementation looks like this:

```
<s:DropDownList prompt="Please Choose" labelField="name" selectedItem="@{overheating.kindOfConstruction}" width="180" styleName="dropDownListStyle">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayCollection>

            <Model:ConstructionKind>
                <Model:name>Massive Construction</Model:name>
                <Model:value>204</Model:value>
            </Model:ConstructionKind>

            <Model:ConstructionKind>
                <Model:name>Lightweight Construction</Model:name>
                <Model:value>60</Model:value>
            </Model:ConstructionKind>

        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:DropDownList>
```

The list is bound to ArrayCollection with two "ConstructionKind" objects. The "ConstructionKind" object implementation is the following:

```
public class ConstructionKind
{
    private var _name:String = '';
    private var _value:Number = 0;

    public function ConstructionKind()
    {
    }
    [Bindable]
    public function get value():Number
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public function set value(value:Number):void
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    [Bindable]
    public function get name():String
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public function set name(value:String):void
    {
        _name = value;
    }

}
```

The selectedItem property of the list is bound to an object which has a bindable property constructionKind of type "ConstructionKind". When I execute the following code the DropDownList is not updated:

```
overheating.kindOfConstruction = new ConstructionKind();
overheating.kindOfConstruction.name = "Massive Construction";
overheating.kindOfConstruction.value = 204;
```

When this is executed the selectedItem of the list is null. My question is:
How does this databinding works? Does it needs the same instance of the object in the dataprovider. Or it is checking the values of the properties of the object?

Comment: Thanks! I am saving the data in XML and when I open it I create a new instance. Can you give me some advice how to achieve automatic selection of the drop down on open?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you have two instances that represent the same data, you should match them by some unique identifier (I guess in your case `value` should do) and then replace one of the instances with the other so you never have any duplicates.